# Deploy web application and console application on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm new on azure so please help me, i have next question:

I have asp .core web application and few simple console applications(not core) that I'm use as services via json rpc.

when I'm hosted on iis i don't have a problem my services was placed on my web app server and recived queries from my web app trough local IP address as 127.0.0.1:port

now I need to move this scheme on azure , how can I deploy my console application services so I can connect them with my web app that will be deployed on azure to ? 
Thank you!

Comment: Insufficient info.  Are you deploying them as SaaS or to an Azure VM(s)?  If it's the latter, it may be a firewall issue as Azure likes to firewall everything by default

Comment: For now I just want to know what solution will be beast in my situation ? I just deploy asp core as web application

Comment: I understand that but how can one comment without understanding your environment

Comment: What about the console apps?  How do you deploy them to Azure?

Comment: I tried deployed them as webjob and failed to get access to them, as I say I'm new in azure and I what know about another solutions

Comment: Sounds like firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy the web application on Azure App Service. Do a bit of rewriting and make use of [Azure Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues) to talk to your Console Applications. Deploy them as WebJobs with a [Queue trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to).

Keep it simple, place a message in a queue, have the WebJob (Console App) read from that queue and do the work. Place the result on disk (`d:\home\site` on App Service) or [Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) and signal with a queue message (or place the result straight into the queue message if it's just a few KB in size).

Alternatively, you may want to look at [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) as *Console Application vNext*.